# How to pass arguments to the callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a react App component. It accepts a `settingsobj` object with a callback function:

```
export const settingsObj = { 
handlers: {
 onClick: (e, dispatch) => { 
   console.log('сработал клик из settingsObj', e);
   dispatch('привет из dispatch'); 
   }
 }
}
```

it combines callbacks using the function concatenateseventhandlers. The resulting callback assigns to button. Code on code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-sun-wgtn4h?file=/src/App.js

The problem is that when I try to pass a function for callback from settingsObj in this case dispatch, then it (dispatch) is always undefined inside callback in the settingsObj object. Please tell me where I made a mistake. PS the error appears when you click on the "click me" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with:

```js
_ownedEventHandlers[keyAddedEventHandlers[i]] = (e, dispatch) =>
            concatFunc(e, dispatch); // uses ---------^ (which is undefined)
```

Here you're updating the `onClick` function to hold `(e, dispatch) => ...`, but React doesn't natively pass `dispatch` as a second argument to the `onClick` function, so instead, `dispatch` is `undefined`. To avoid shadowing the `dispatch` that you're passing into your `concatenatesEventHandlers` function, you should remove the `dispatch` argument from the above arrow function:

```js
_ownedEventHandlers[keyAddedEventHandlers[i]] = (e) =>
            concatFunc(e, dispatch); // <--- uses `dispatch` passed into `concatenatesEventHandlers`
```

Comment: Thank you Nick for your help. Your answer worked. I realized what my mistake was.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
export const settingsObj = (dispatch) => ({
  handlers: {
    onClick: (e) => {
      console.log('сработал клик из settingsObj', e);
      dispatch('привет из dispatch');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe it will work too. But I can't replace an object with a function

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code.

Comment: @GertArnold i'm sorry for my bad answer, i'm a new hand and i will improve this.  thank you